# I want replace index array. example $array[x][y] to $array[y][x]

Tags: php, arrays

Example. I have:

```
Array (

[0] => Array (
[comments_id] => 1 
[comments_text] => blabla1
) 

[1] => Array (
[comments_id] => 2 
[comments_text] => blabla2
) 

)
```

I want have:

```
Array (

[comments_id] => Array (
[0] => 1 
[1] => 2 
)

[comments_text] => Array (
[0] => blabla1 
[1] => blabla2

)
```

In simplified wants to replace
`$array[x][y]` to `$array[y][x]`
I writing in php.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this

```
// the final array which will hold your result array
// considering $results contains your previous array
$final_array = array();
foreach($results as $result) {
    $final_array['comments_id'][] = $result['comments_id'];
    $final_array['comments_text'][] = $result['comments_text'];
}
```